Table Study Error: Row 60 is out of table bounds, number of rows is 60
I've been building on an existing published study and expanding the number of bars from 10 to 30.Apparently I've got an error in the counting of rows which I am not seeing how to fix. Can you help me? I adjusted row values by 1 integer at a time and that did not uncover the study error.
This script gets OHLC values from any security and Higher/Same time frame you set, then creates the chart including last 30 candles. Closing price text color changes by the real-time candle of the related symbol and time frame. All this was made using the Tables in Pine and the chart location doesn't change even if you change the size of main chart window.
Almost everything can be change as you want. You can change/set:

Colors of Body and Top/Bottom Wicks separately
The Height of each Cell
The Width of Body and Wicks
The Background and Frame color

//@version=5
indicator("HTF insert 1W 30 bars", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 50)

HTF = input.timeframe(defval = "1W", title = "Higher Time Frame", group = "Higher Time Frame")
symbolu = input.string(defval = "", title = "Symbol", tooltip = "If you leave the Symbol empty then current symbol is used")
backgcolor = input.color(defval = color.new(color.black, 0), title = "Background Color", group = "Chart")
//backgcolor = input.color(defval = color.new(#e5e6e9, 0), title = "Background Color", group = "Chart")
frmcolor = input.color(defval = color.silver, title = "Frame Color", group = "Chart")

//bodycolorup = input.color(defval = color.black, title = "Body", inline = "bodycol", group = "Candles") //color.green
//bodycolordn = input.color(defval = color.black, title = "", inline = "bodycol", group = "Candles") // color.red
//topwickcolor = input.color(defval = color.black, title = "Wick", inline = "wickcol", group = "Candles") // color.red
//bottomwickcolor = input.color(defval = color.black, title = "", inline = "wickcol", group = "Candles") // color.green

bodycolorup = input.color(defval = color.new(color.green, 30), title = "Body", inline = "bodycol", group = "Candles") //color.green
bodycolordn = input.color(defval = color.new(color.red, 30), title = "", inline = "bodycol", group = "Candles") // color.red
topwickcolor = input.color(defval = color.new(color.red, 30), title = "Wick", inline = "wickcol", group = "Candles") // color.red
bottomwickcolor = input.color(defval = color.new(color.green, 30), title = "", inline = "wickcol", group = "Candles") // color.green


cellwidthbody = input.float(defval = 0.2, title = "Body Width", minval = 0.001, step = 0.1, group = "Candles") 
cellwidthwick = input.float(defval = 0.3, title = "Wick Width", minval = 0.001, step = 0.05, group = "Candles")
cellheight = input.float(defval = 1.4, title = "Cell Height", minval = 0.001, step = 0.1, group = "Candles")
tableposy = input.string(defval='bottom', title='Chart Location', options=['bottom', 'middle', 'top'], inline='chartpos', group = "Chart")
tableposx = input.string(defval='left', title='', options=['left', 'center', 'right'], inline='chartpos', group = "Chart")


var symbol = symbolu == "" ? syminfo.tickerid : symbolu
float highest = request.security(symbol, HTF, ta.highest(20))  // 20
float lowest = request.security(symbol, HTF, ta.lowest(20))    // 20
bool highest_or_lowest_changed = highest != highest[1] or lowest != lowest[1]
float mintick = (highest - lowest) / 50

get_ohlc(int [] ohcl_array, int index, float highest, float lowest)=>
    [o, h, l, c] =  request.security(symbol, HTF, [open[index], high[index], low[index], close[index]])
    
    array.push(ohcl_array, 5 + math.ceil((highest - o) / mintick) - 1) // open
    array.push(ohcl_array, 5 + math.ceil((highest - h) / mintick) - 1) // high
    array.push(ohcl_array, 5 + math.ceil((highest - l) / mintick) - 1) // low
    array.push(ohcl_array, 5 + math.ceil((highest - c) / mintick) - 1) // close

draw_candle_part(table mychart, int index, int up, int down, int left, int right, color colour)=>
    if up <= down
        for y = up to down
            for x = left to right
                table.cell(table_id = mychart, column = 119 - index * 4 - x, row = y, width = (x % 2) == 0 ? cellwidthbody : cellwidthwick, height = cellheight, bgcolor = colour)
            
draw_candle(int [] ohcl_array, table mychart, int index)=>
    colour = array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 3) <= array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4) ? bodycolorup : bodycolordn

    // top wick
    draw_candle_part(mychart, index, array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 1), math.min(array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 0), array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 3)) - 1, 1, 1, topwickcolor)
    // bottom wick
    draw_candle_part(mychart, index, math.max(array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 0), array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 3)) + 1, array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 2), 1, 1, bottomwickcolor)
    // body
    draw_candle_part(mychart, index, math.min(array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 0), array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 3)),  math.max(array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 0), array.get(ohcl_array, index * 4 + 3)), 0, 2, colour)  


draw_rt_candle(int [] ohcl_array, table mychart)=>
    // clean candle
    for x = 77 to 79  // 77 to 79
        for y = 0 to 59  
            table.cell(table_id = mychart, column = x, row = y, width = (x % 2) == 1 ? cellwidthbody : cellwidthwick, height = cellheight, bgcolor = backgcolor)
    // draw candle
    draw_candle(ohcl_array, mychart, 0)
    
ohcl_array = array.new_int(0)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 0, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 1, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 2, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 3, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 4, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 5, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 6, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 7, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 8, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 9, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 10, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 11, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 12, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 13, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 14, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 15, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 16, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 17, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 18, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 19, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 20, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 21, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 22, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 23, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 24, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 25, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 26, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 27, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 28, highest, lowest)
get_ohlc(ohcl_array, 29, highest, lowest)

symbolclose = str.tostring(request.security(symbol, HTF, math.round_to_mintick(close)))
symbolhighest = str.tostring(request.security(symbol, HTF, math.round_to_mintick(highest)))
symbollowest = str.tostring(request.security(symbol, HTF, math.round_to_mintick(lowest)))

newbar = ta.change(time(HTF)) != 0 
var mychart = table.new(position = tableposy + '_' + tableposx, columns = 129, rows= 65, frame_width = 1, frame_color = frmcolor, border_width = 0)


if barstate.islast
    var isfirst = true
    if isfirst or newbar or highest_or_lowest_changed
        
        isfirst := false
        //redraw table
        for x = 0 to 120 
            for y = 0 to 64
            //for y = 0 to 59
                table.cell(table_id = mychart, column = x, row = y, width = (x % 2) == 1 ? cellwidthbody : cellwidthwick, height = cellheight, bgcolor = backgcolor)
        
        for x = 0 to 29 // 19
            draw_candle(ohcl_array, mychart, x)
            
    else if not isfirst
        draw_rt_candle(ohcl_array, mychart)


